# JSP Statements Not Interpreted in a DCP

Tags: 2013-sp1, content-delivery, broker, jsp

I've a DCP that renders a JSP statement `<% out.println("Hello"); %>`. I'm trying to execute the JSP statement by using the CD API on a static JSP page. I've tried all possible scenarios - making the DCP a REL and publishing it to the broker and making it a JSP and publishing it to the file system, but I'm not able to have the JSP statement executed.

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Made the DCP a JSP and configured the `cd_storage_conf.xml` to publish DCPs to the file system. The DCP goes to the file system as a JSP and I used the `ComponentPresentationAssembler` to execute the JSP statement. All I see on the page is the JSP statement rendered as-is. The static JSP page looks like this:

```
JSPPage dcdPage = new JSPPage(pageContext, "tcm:17-28489-64");
ComponentPresentationAssembler cpAssembler = new  ComponentPresentationAssembler(dcdPage);
out.println(cpAssembler.getContent(20154,1029));
```

2. Made the DCP a REL and configured the `cd_storage_conf.xml` to publish DCPs to the broker database. The DCP goes to the broker and I used the `ComponentPresentationAssembler` to execute the JSP statement, but still no luck. The page has the JSP statement rendered as-is.

I've looked into TREX, but couldn't find anything that helps resolve this issue. There was something similar [Java code in DCP not exectued](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3211/java-code-in-dcp-not-exectued), but that too doesn't seem to have a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update 1:**

Using the code above doesn't seem to call the JSPProcessor. I believe it just gets the file from the location and displays it. The log shows no errors in this case.

> 2016-12-05 21:41:06,796 DEBUG FSComponentPresentationDAO - Retrieving
>   default data location for publication: 17 2016-12-05 21:41:06,796
>   DEBUG FSComponentPresentationDAO - Looking for location for component
>   presentation type: JSP 2016-12-05 21:41:06,797 DEBUG
>   FSComponentPresentationDAO - FSComponentPresentationDAO.getFile():
>   Location found: C:\test\WebContent\dcp 2016-12-05 21:41:06,799
>   DEBUG ComponentPresentationAssembler -
>   ComponentPresentation.getContent(componentId=19894;templateId=1029)
>   found:
>   com.tridion.storage.mapper.componentpresentations.JSPComponentPresentationImpl@14f2b1ba

However, if I use tridion tags, the JSPProcessor is called and there's an error thrown. Nothing gets rendered on the page.

```
<tridion:ComponentPresentation templateURI="tcm:17-1029-32" pageURI="tcm:17-28489-64" componentURI="tcm:17-20154"></tridion:ComponentPresentation>
```

The log shows an error here.

> 2016-12-05 21:50:03,298 DEBUG ComponentPresentationAssembler -
>   ComponentPresentation.getContent(...) running JSP
>   ComponentPresentation 2016-12-05 21:50:03,298 DEBUG JSPProcessor -
>   JSPProcessor.run(...) absolutePath of cp:
>   C:\test\WebContent\dcp\dcp1029_19894.jsp 
>   2016-12-05 21:50:03,298 DEBUG JSPProcessor - JSPProcessor.run(...) documentroot C:.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\test\
>   **2016-12-05 21:50:03,298 ERROR JSPProcessor - JSPProcessor.run(...) The
>   JSP ComponentPresentation is not located in the documentroot of your
>   website;
>   C:.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\test;C:\test\WebContent\dcp\dcp1029_19894.jsp**

My question now is why does the JSPProcessor looking in the web root? Shouldn't it be looking in the **sub-directory** that's defined in the `cd_storage_conf.xml`?

Comment: Putting the DCP on the FS is the right path. Your issue is because you're printing the DCP as a string in your code. You need to not render the DCP as a string, but run it as an include instead. Check if the API has a method or property to get your the FS path to the item.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're publishing to the filesystem, then you'll need to set the Component Template to output JSP, use the `ComponentPresentationAssembler` class and **ensure that the DCPs are being published to a sub-directory of your website by the Deployer**.

If you're publishing as REL, you'll need to set the Component Template to output REL, configure the Deployer to publish these to the Broker database. You could try using the `PageContentAssembler` class (rather than the `ComponentPresentationAssembler` one).

For more details please see the [Content Delivery Namespaces](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-BAEA33D3-F6D5-443E-AA29-554EA0817B55) page in the online documentation.

Comment: ISTR that you /can/ use the ComponentPresentationAssembler with REL.... although that documentation is very vague on that point, and my memory isn't 100% trustworthy.

Comment: That's interesting to know, Dominic. I've only used PageContentAssembler with REL (quite a while ago) and this worked.

Comment: I've updated my answer to clarify that you can use either `PageContentAssembler` or `ComponentPresentationAssembler` when working with REL.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan! The CT is outputted as a JSP under `dcp/jsp` sub-directory of the website and I'm using the `ComponentPresentationAssembler`, but the issue is the JSP statements in the CT aren't getting executed. It renders as-is.

Comment: What happens if you just put the write out (<% out.println("Hello"); %>) in the JSP page (and not in a DCP). I presume that it renders okay there? Is there anything in the CD log files (you may need to lower these to DEBUG)?